# How to create a neste array and transform to a nested hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested

I am trying to create a nested hash in ruby.  The following is the code I am using to first create a nested array and then nested hash.

```
r=[]
y=[]
z={}

r= [["1776"], ["1094"], ["1666", "1077"]]

i=1

r.each do |t|
    t.each do |h|
        y << {:link => h, :group => i} 
    end 
    i = i + 1 
end 

y.each { |k,v| z[k] = v }
```

However, I keep end up the following output when I put 'p z':

```
{{:link=>"1776", :group=>1}=>nil, {:link=>"1094", :group=>2}=>nil 
{:link=>"1666", :group=>3}=>nil, {:link=>"1077", :group=>3}=>nil}
```

My goal is to create a structure something like this:

```
{{:link=>"1666" {:group=>3}}, {:link=>"1077" {:group=>3}}}
```

I want to use the link key and value to merge this array of hashes with anothoer array based on matching :link= value, and then be able to call on each of the sub-array elements based on the :link key.

Also, when every I try to do anything with the hash, I get "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"  Not sure what I am doing wrong and why I get the nil.  I have tried flattening and that did not help.

Comment: What is your expected output structure?

Comment: What is `r`? What is the nature of `t`? `i`, `y` and `z` are not initialized. Give us an example (by editing your question) and maybe we can help. Specify `r` (as a valid Ruby object) and show us your desired result ("output"), also as a valid Ruby object.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code doesn't work. `r`, `y`, and `i` are undefined.

Comment: Sorry, only my second time posting and I did think it through.  I have added some additional detial.  It also gave me a chance to think more about the date structure I would like to have at the end.

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid object.

Comment: Your desired output is broken, and strange, why have a hash at all if you have every information in it duplicated? This makes no sense to me, please extend your question to show what you want to do in the end with the output...

Answer (score 0):

```
y.each do |h|
  h.each { |k,v| z[k] = v }
end
```

Should work. The problem is, your array has multiple Elements which are looking like that: `{ :link=>"1776", :group=>1 }`. That is one element. Now you use a `each` block with two elements `k` and `v`. Since there is only one `k` will be that one (`k` = `{ :link=>"1776", :group=>1 }`) and `v` will be `nil`.

**Note: This is not the most elegant solution for sure**, but it explains your error. Your example code does not make too much of a sense. To get a good, elegant solution **update your question like asked in the comments**.

Comment: Hi, this is probably a stupid question, but how do I escape out all of the hash values.  Presently, this is only save the last value to "z".